# Is there a way to use formulas as events in Mixpanel funnels?

Tags: analytics

Whenever my app is opened, I send either an "account retrieved" or "account created" event. I could additionally send an "app opened" event, but that feels unnecessary since the account created/retrieved events already capture it. I can create an "app opened" formula, but then I can't see a way of using that formula in funnels.

Is there a solution or workaround that will achieve this?

Comment: What if somebody opens the app for the first time but doesn't actually create an account?   Wouldn't you want a separate event for "app opened" so that you could measure this drop off rate?

Comment: Potentially (in my case actually not for technical reasons), but there are other circumstances where I want to have the same functionality. For example, the user makes a binary decision, and I want to capture what the response was as well as the fact that they responded. Currently, I have three events (responded, responded:yes, responded:no) whereas I would only need two if I could combine the "responded:yes" and "responded:no" events.